# Regular Expression for semantic library word level match

Tags: regex, wildcard, synonym

I have semantic library containing database fields with possible/matching matching synonyms in previous column i.e. goods id | products_id - items id | products_id - things id | products_id.

I am required to match above fields in result of user entered utterance and have the system to select the relevant database field ( in above case "products_id").

The problem is that user might mention above synonym to their choice and matching function can fail if the word order is removed i.e.:

User: Show me the id of goods.

User: I want to see items and their id.

User: can you display things with id numbers.

Could you advise on what accurate regular expression syntax/combination should be used in this case as its quite laborious and I am trying different ways to make it work. So far I have tried positive lookahead but not sure.

```
^(?=.*goods)(?=.*id).*$
```

Comment: This question is not very well explained. What do you mean by `synonyms in previous column` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this regex:

```
^(?=.*\b(?:goods?|things?|items?)\b)(?=.*\bid\b).*$
                                ^---place here if you want to add more
```

Place your words inside the `(...)` separated with a pipe(`|`). Notice, I have used `s?` which means s can exists or not. For example `goods?` with support both `good` and `goods`

Try this [Online Demo](http://regex101.com/r/qW0jL2)

Comment: What is the difference between                                               ^(?=.*\b(?:goods?|things?|items?)\b)(?=.*\b(?:id)\b).*$                         and                                                                              ^(?=.*\b(?:goods?|things?|items?)\b)(?=.*\b(?:id)\b).*$                             thanks in advance

Comment: I didn't find any difference. I found both are identical.

Comment: sorry Sabuj, ^(?=.*\b(?:goods?|things?|items?)\b)(?=.*\b(?:id)\b).*$   and ^(?=.*\b(?:goods?|things?|items?)\b)(?=.*\bid\b).*$                     I have changed it. Can you have look again. Thanks

Comment: There is no difference, only is you are writing few texts more for `(?:..)`

Comment: Hi Sabuj, can I trouble you by asking on how to edit pattern to find one word on specific position in every user utterance. i.e. from above pattern, word <id> should always come with variable goods?|things?|items?. What I am looking for is to set condition similar to \b(?=.*id)(?=.*goods?|things?|items?)\b so <id> appearing on its own like \b(?=.*id)("missing variable")\b and with out variable (goods?|things?|items?) can be detected.